# Generating a fingerprint for spotify android api

Tags: java, android, authentication, spotify

so I'm following the Spotify android [API beginner tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/) and I'm stuck on what to do to register an application fingerprint. The tutorial says this;

> You need to register a development fingerprint to be able to interact with Spotify in the debug version of your application.
>
> It is possible to register multiple fingerprints for the application, which can be useful if there are more than one developer working with your app that wants to communicate with Spotify.
>
> On Windows run:
>
> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore -list -v | grep SHA1

The problem is that last line of code I need to run. It never specifies what to run it on. Do I run it on the command prompt? I tried but it didnt work and got the message "'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command." What do I do?